# How can I change the time between frames? in a gganimate plot map

Tags: r, maps, gganimate, geom-sf

I want to do a animate plot where the color of each region of Spain change each month. I am using the transition_manual but there is no posibility of arraging the time between frames. The plot is:

```
ggplot(df_g_m) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = as.factor(group)), linewidth = 0.01) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols,
                    labels = c("<1", "[1,25)", "[25,50)",
                               "[50,100)", "[100,200)", "[200,400]", ">400"),
                    name = "range") +
  geom_sf(data = can_box) + coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, "cm")) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Month: {current_frame}") +
  transition_manual(as.factor(month))
```

Does anyone know how to change the time between each frame?